# CodeIgniter RESTful and controller

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i am new to CI and MVC in general and i am trying to make a REStful application.

I have read a lot (really) and i have the following specification

**RESTful**

Read (GET)

```
/object
/object.xml 
/object.json
```

Read id (GET)

```
/object/id
/object/id.xml 
/object/id.json
```

Create (POST)

```
/object
/object.xml 
/object.json
```

Update (PUT)

```
/object/id
/object/id.xml 
/object/id.json
```

Delete (DELETE)

```
/object/id
/object/id.xml 
/object/id.json
```

Based on the above when extension is .xml return xml, when .json returns json and on extension returns html

When comes to CI CRUD i have the followig urls

```
 /object
 /object/edit/id
 /odject/delete/id
```

My question is

Do i need 2 controllers 1 for RESTful and 1 for CI CRUD or i can have only 1,
and how can i have the multiple respesentation (html,xml,json).

Any help appricated (link for reading too)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

You can also do this a different way, however I think the above is probably the best place to start.

**Update**

Another way, could be to use routes.

```
$routes['object\.(xml|http|json)'] = 'process_object/$1';
$routes['object/(:num)\.(xml|http|json)'] = 'process_object/$2/$1';
$routes['object/crud/\.(xml|http|json)'] = 'process_object/$1/null/true';
$routes['object/crud/(:num)\.(xml|http|json)'] = 'process_object/$2/$1/true';
```

Then your `process_object` action:

```
function process_object($Format = 'xml', $ID = null, $CRUD = false)
{
    $method = $this->_detect_method(); // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540781/get-a-put-request-with-codeigniter
    $view = null;
    $data = array();
    switch($method)
    {
        case 'get' :
        {
            if($CRUD !== false)
                $view = 'CRUD/Get';
            if($ID === null)
            {
                // get a list
                $data['Objects'] = $this->my_model->Get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data['Objects'] = $this->my_model->GetById($ID);
            }
        }
        break;
        case 'put' :
        {
            if($CRUD !== false)
                $view = 'CRUD/Put';
            $this->my_model->Update($ID, $_POST);
        }
        break;
        case 'post' :
        {
            if($CRUD !== false)
                $view = 'CRUD/Post';
            $this->my_model->Insert($_POST);
        }
        break;
        case 'delete' :
        {
            if($CRUD !== false)
                $view = 'CRUD/Delete';
            $this->my_model->Delete($ID);
        }
        break;
    }
    if($view != null)
    {
        $this->load->view($view, $data);
    }
    else
    {
        switch(strtolower($Format))
        {
            case 'xml' :
            {
                // create and output XML based on $data.
                header('content-type: application/xml');
            }
            break;
            case 'json' :
            {
                // create and output JSON based on $data.
                header('content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            break;
            case 'xml' :
            {
                // create and output HTML based on $data.
                header('content-type: text/html');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code in anyway, so it will need work.

Comment: Thank i have already watch this, but this one has a restfull controller extend and not CI.So its not clear for me if i must have 2 controller because 2 controllers is double work.Thank anyway

Comment: You could "potentially" have one controller, however it may complicate things by doing so. Another way I was looking at, was to use Routes. See my updated answer.