# DELETE method on jQuery Blueimp FileUpload not allowed using Codeigniter/PHP (405 error)?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, file-upload, delete-file

I'm trying to delete files using this very nice [jQuery Blueimp File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I put this plugin in my root directory and was able to upload and delete files no problem.

However, when I embed this plugin within my codeigniter app I'm no longer to delete files I've uploaded due to a 405 error. I've set all the folders to `777` just to make sure that isn't an issue.

Any thoughts? Here's my console log:

[image: Console.log]

Comment: That's not a filesystem permissions issue - your webserver is not allowing DELETE actions.

Comment: i'm using Apache. If this is a webserver issue why is it allowing DELETE **outside** of my codeigniter app but not **inside** of it?

Comment: Check for a `<limit>` directive somewhere. Just because it works in one place but not another doesn't mean much - apache allows overrides on all sorts of levels - per vhost, per dir, per url, blah blah blah.

Comment: Worth checking in on handling alternative HTTP verbs w/ CI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540781/get-a-put-request-with-codeigniter

Comment: @MarcB can you be more specific on where I should look for the `<limit>` directive? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Not a clue. that's entirely up to your system's configuration/layout. it could be anywhere up the doc-root of your site, or a .conf file somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my own problem following the code in [one of the Codeigniter Forks](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter) of this Blueimp plugin.

The problem was the URL of the DELETE HTTP/AJAX request that the Blueimp plugin specifies by default. Those URLs correspond to a directory path of where the file is uploaded. Unfortunately, Codeigniter by default overrides this by using the URL to determine what controller/controller_method to call.

So for example, my directory structure for the uploaded file is this:

```
/uploads/img1.jpg
```

and Codeigniter looked for a controller called `uploads` and a method called `img1.jpg` but those obviously didn't exist.

I solved this by changing the Blueimp plugin "upload.class.php" file  `delete_url` that gets assigned to each file. The `delete_url` was changed from a directory location to a codeigniter controller/controller_method as follows:

```
protected function set_file_delete_url($file) { 
    $file->delete_url = base_url().'upload/deleteFile/'.rawurlencode($file->name);
    //"upload/deleteFile is my controller/controller_method
    //$file->delete_url = $this->options['upload_url']
    //    .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);*/
    //.....
```

and then here is what my `upload/deleteFile` function looks like (again following the code nearly verbatim in [the Codeigniter Blueimp Fork](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter)):

```
    function deleteFile($file){

    $fcpath=FCPATH.'uploads/;
    $success =unlink($fcpath.$file); //PHP function was does the actual file deletion
            //info to see if it is doing what it is supposed to 
    $info->sucess =$success;
    $info->file =is_file(FCPATH .$file);
    $info->fcpath = FCPATH;
    if (IS_AJAX) {
        //I don't think it matters if this is set but good for error checking in the console/firebug
        echo json_encode(array($info));
    }
    else {     
        //here you will need to decide what you want to show for a successful delete
        $file_data['delete_data'] = $file;
        $this->load->view('admin/delete_success', $file_data); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should only modify this file UploadHandler.php:

function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
           
 // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
           
 // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
           
 //'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            
**'delete_type' => 'POST',**

Comment: It did the trick, in CakePHP 2.5.5, another MVC! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, in the following way:

in the file: UploadHandler.php, in the constructor

**Before:**

```
$this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
```

**Add to the end my load control method**

```
$this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')).'/cargar'
```

**Just add the route pointing to the method you created to upload your files.**

Answer (score 0):

I added the jquery file upload to a controller in my application. Like Mark, I could not get the files deleted. But I solved the problem like this:

In the constructor, the first element of the *options* array

```
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
```

remove the reference to SCRIPT_FILENAME

remove the reference to SCRIPT_FILENAME and add the name of the driver that loads the *uploadhandler.php* library. In my case, *fileupload*

```
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/fileupload/',
```

Ready. Just try!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the "script_url" inside "UploadHandler" and point it to where your "UploadHandler" library is called.

//BEFORE

```
$this->options = array(
'script_url'=>$this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
```

//AFTER

```
$this->options = array(
'script_url'=>base_url().'admin/categories/category_manage/picturesupload'
```

Because i am using bonfire-CI thats why
"admin" for admin panel 
"categories" is the name of context
"category_manage" is the name of module
"picturesupload" is the name of method in which i am loading the libarary

If you are not using bonfire then simply change it to "your controller name"/"your method name where the UploadHandler libaray is called"

//"picturesupload" method look like this

```
public function picturesupload(){

        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        $this->load->library('UploadHandler');

}
```